# create lo file by loki logs and store in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, grafana, grafana-loki

In `Loki`, I want to create log  file named ddmmyyyy.logs format and store in s3 bucket. file is stored in s3 bucket but with something other name how can I achieve this. this is my loki-local-config.yaml

```
auth_enabled: false
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 50053
ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  wal:
    dir: "/tmp/wal"
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: "2023-07-01"
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: s3
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: loki_index_
        period: 24h
storage_config:
  aws:
    region: "ap-south-1"
    bucketnames: abc
    endpoint: s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
    access_key_id: ********************
    secret_access_key: *********************
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /loki/boltdb-shipper-active
    cache_location: /loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
    cache_ttl: 24h
    shared_store: s3
limits_config:
  retention_period: 168h
compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/compactor
  shared_store: s3
  compaction_interval: 10m
```

Comment: So you want Loki to create a file per day right ?